# How can I Display database table record in textfields by clicking a value in dropdown list

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am new in this page, and I came with my problem while looking for help from someone who is liable. I have my database with the name "e_exam" and a table named "course". The table has this columns (coursecode, department, level). Therefore, I used this code:

```
  <select name="ex_coursecode">
    <option disabled selected>-- Select Course Code --</option><br><br>
 
 <?php
     //display course code to dropdownlist
     $course = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT coursecode From course");  // Use select query here 

      while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($course))
       {
             echo "<option value='". $data['coursecode'] ."'>" .$data['coursecode'] ."</option>";  // displaying data in option menu
         }  
?>
</select>
```

to display the values of "course" table to my dropdown and it works successfully.
Now, I want to display the values of the "course" table to textfields.
Someone should help me please.

Comment: Show an example output you expect

Comment: Ok, let me shore the expected output